# Retrieving PDF from MySql DB to android(using Volley)

Tags: php, android, android-intent, android-volley

hello i have a Table that has some pdf files in it 
like so 
(note i am storing pdfs using php and the api i will be using to send the pdf file with be just simple php)

**Table**

```
id(INT) | book_name(BLOB)
   1    | book_one
   2    | book_two
   3    | book_three
```

and my android application will look something like this

[Android Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GJt17.png)

is it possible to load pdf from a JSON (using php) to android and display it in such a manner

if some one could provide me to the correct tutorial or help me do this i would be very glad 
i am a noob in android programming and any assistance will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Sure, I would load the BLOB data, store to a temporary file somewhere in the App's data directory and then display it with https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/pdf/PdfRenderer.html

About "is it possible to load pdf from a JSON": Yes you can store any BLOB in json as a base64 encoded string. In this case, after loading, parsing the json, reading and decoding you can save it again as temporary file and display with PDFRenderer. For base64 decoding on Android check this https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Base64 for encoding in php you could use base64_encode()

I do not think there is a tutorial for your specific complex use case. I would go forward in the following steps:

1. Work on loading the pure pdf BLOB from your database and store it as file locally, until you can open it successfully in a normal PDF reader app
2. Now that you know your tmp.pdf file is correctly restored and should be renderable, try to render it inside your app with android.graphics.pdf.PdfRenderer - this is step 2 because you already know your problem is not the file when you run into problems
3. Next try step 1 and 2 with a base64 encoded pdf blob in a json string
4. done

Find what you could use, learn how to use it quickly, check if it solves your problem in part and then bringing the puzzle pieces together to your solution is the regular drill I would say. There is not a tutorial on everything, often only the basic usage.